# VC++ OLE DB: how to cancel query?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, oledb

Sometimes user run long-time query to SQL Server in application (vc++ OLE DB).
How to cancel this query on the client side during the execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ICommand interface has a [Cancel method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is specifically meant for cancelling a query.  If you are using ADO, then the previously mentioned method is still available via [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).